# Sort a DateTime Column with a Calendar

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, calendar

The `UserLoginPerDay` column in my database has a `DateTime` property. The idea is that I grab that column with some other columns and display it on my asp.net website in a grid view.

However I noticed while writing this statement that I have to input a time value else it will not show any records. I just want to be able to select a day in my calendar and every record that is equal to that day will show up, ignoring time.

I am using a `SqlDataSource`

ASPX page

```
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" 
    onselectionchanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged"></asp:Calendar>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LoginProject %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT UserLoginToday.UserId, Gebruikers.Lastname, Gebruikers.Firstname, UserLoginToday.UserLoginPerDay FROM Gebruikers INNER JOIN UserLoginToday ON Gebruikers.UserId = UserLoginToday.UserId WHERE (UserLoginToday.UserLoginPerDay = ISNULL(@datefilter, UserLoginToday.UserLoginPerDay))" CancelSelectOnNullParameter="false"><SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Calendar1" Name="datefilter" 
            PropertyName="SelectedDate" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: It's a **column** (not a *collum* as you keep writing.....)

Comment: ^^ Sorry mate, English is not my first language.

Comment: That's ok - that's why I'm mentioning it - pick it up and use it in the future, and your English has become better again! :-)

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: `Convert(date,UserLoginToday.UserLoginPerDay)` if you are using Sql Server 2008 or higher.

Comment: @TheDonger The comment from Matthew is where I was going too, so no need to answer that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DateTime includes both date and time data. Unless all the rows in the database have a 0 as the time part and your application also sends 0 as the time part, they'll never be equal.

If your database is MS's SQL Server, I'd suggest you use the [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms189794%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) function to compare dates.

```
DATEDIFF(DAY, date1, date2) = 0
```

is true if both dates are the same, ignoring the time part of the value.

Comment: I'm useing MS's SQL Server, Can you show me where to implement it into my statement?

Comment: I think it should be something like

`WHERE (DATEDIFF(DAY, UserLoginToday.UserLoginPerDay, ISNULL(@datefilter, UserLoginToday.UserLoginPerDay)) = 0)`

Comment: Although you may as well change it to `WHERE (@datefilter IS NULL OR DATEDIFF(DAY, UserLoginToday.UserLoginPerDay, @datefilter) = 0)`. Unless I've made a typo this avoids unnecessary comparisons when you give a null value.

Comment: This worked for me, but now when i write my records to my GridView it will display the date and always the 00:00:00 behind it. Can i hide that? Or display the time that is in the record?

Comment: That's a different question, it's about formatting the values. Even if I knew how to (I'm not very familiar with asp.net) it would be off-topic here.